# Showing 2 graph exported from fusion charts

Tags: charts, export, fusioncharts

I'm crazy trying to show two graph from fusion charts. Two graph was succeed save to server. But i have a problem to show them in html. If one graph is no problem for me.
This is my html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">function FC_Exported(objRtn){ 
var namaFile;          
if (objRtn.statusCode=="1"){
namaFile=objRtn.fileName;
//alert("The chart was successfully saved on server. The file can be accessed from " + objRtn.fileName);
}else{
//alert("The chart could not be saved on server. There was an error. Description : " + objRtn.statusMessage);
}
document.getElementById('imgdiv1').innerHTML="<img src='"+objRtn.fileName+"'><br>";           
document.getElementById('imgdiv2').innerHTML="<img src='"+objRtn.fileName+"'><br>";           
document.getElementById("chartdiv1").style.display='none';
document.getElementById("chartdiv2").style.display='none';
}
</script>   
</head>
<body>  
<div id="chartdiv1" style="text-align:center">Loading Chart... </div><div id="chartdiv2" style="text-align:center">Loading Chart... </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var chart2 = new FusionCharts("charts/MSColumn3D_new.swf", "chart1Id", "600", "400", "0", "1");                   
chart2.setXMLUrl("data.xml");
chart2.render("chartdiv1");
chart2.addEventListener("Rendered", function () { FusionCharts("chart1Id").exportChart();  } ); 
var chart1 = new FusionCharts("charts/MSColumn3D_new.swf", "chart2Id", "600", "400", "0", "1");chart1.setXMLUrl("test.xml"); chart1.render("chartdiv2");
chart1.addEventListener("Rendered", function () { FusionCharts("chart2Id").exportChart();  } );     
</script>
<div id="imgdiv1" align="center"></div><div id="imgdiv2" align="center"></div>
```

and these is my xml :

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<graph bgColor='e6f2f6' palette='2' caption='Anggaran Jenis Tahun sebelumnya' subcaption=' ' xAxisName='Uraian' decimalSeparator=',' thousandSeparator='.' yAxisName='Nilai (dalam Rupiah)' showValues='0' decimals='0' formatNumberScale='0' showPercentInToolTip='1' showpercentvalues='0' exportShowMenuItem='0' exportEnabled='1' exportAtClient='0' exportAction='save' exportHandler='ExportHandlers/PHP/FCExporter.php'>
<categories font='Arial' fontSize='11' fontColor='000000'>
<category name='4.1 ' />
<category name='4.2 ' />
<category name='4.3 ' />
<category name='5.1 ' />
<category name='5.2 ' />
<category name='6.1 ' />
<category name='6.2 ' />
</categories>
<dataset seriesname='Tahun 2013' color='2AD62A'>
<set value='26670448766000' />
<set value='9248954435000' />
<set value='5605933431000' />
<set value='14582865662703' />
<set value='30993463301297' />
<set value='8454553000000' />
<set value='4403560668000' />
</dataset>
<dataset seriesname='Tahun 2012' color='F1683C'>
<set value='20523433370351' />
<set value='9776877857000' />
<set value='3349700731266' />
<set value='12552587002387' />
<set value='25814093071454' />
<set value='7703218490508' />
<set value='2986550375284' />
</dataset>
</graph>


<?xml version='1.0'?>
<graph bgColor='e6f2f6' palette='2' caption='Anggaran Kelompok' subcaption=' ' xAxisName='Uraian' decimalSeparator=',' thousandSeparator='.' yAxisName='Nilai (dalam Rupiah)' showValues='0' decimals='0' formatNumberScale='0' showPercentInToolTip='1' showpercentvalues='0' exportShowMenuItem='0' exportEnabled='1' exportAtClient='0' exportAction='save' exportHandler='ExportHandlers/PHP/FCExporter.php'><categories font='Arial' fontSize='11' fontColor='000000'>
<category name='4.1 ' />
<category name='4.2 ' />
<category name='4.3 ' />
<category name='5.1 ' />
<category name='5.2 ' />
<category name='6.1 ' />
<category name='6.2 ' />
</categories>
<dataset seriesname='Tahun 2013' color='2AD62A'>
<set value='26670448766000' />
<set value='9248954435000' />
<set value='5605933431000' />
<set value='14582865662703' />
<set value='30993463301297' />
<set value='8454553000000' />
<set value='4403560668000' />
</dataset>
<dataset seriesname='Tahun 2012' color='F1683C'>
<set value='20523433370351' />
<set value='9776877857000' />
<set value='3349700731266' />
<set value='12552587002387' />
<set value='25814093071454' />
<set value='7703218490508' />
<set value='2986550375284' />
</dataset>
</graph>
```

How to get two file name exported image?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to export more than one chart appearing in the same page, Batch exporting of chart is supported while rendering in Flash mode.

For demo, please refer to :http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/Code/ExportChartSamples/BatchExport/BatchModeOnly.html